# how do i integrate ccavenue payment gateway in my Laravel api for mobile application

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

how do i integrate ccavenue payment gateway in my  **Laravel Application** . i want to implement this in a web service api for android.actually i want to know about how to integrate cc-avenue payment gateway on mobile checkout page in my android application with laravel

Answer (score 0):

install

```php
composer require kishanio/ccavenue
```

use

```php
use Kishnio\CCAvenue\Payment as CCAvenueClient;


$ccavenue = new CCAvenueClient( '<merchant_id>', '<working_key>', '<redirect_url>' );

// set details 
$ccavenue->setAmount( '<Amount>' );
$ccavenue->setOrderId( '<order_id>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingName( '<billing_cust_name>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingAddress( '<billing_cust_address>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingCity( '<billing_cust_city>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingZip( '<billing_cust_zip>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingState( '<billing_cust_state>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingCountry( '<billing_cust_country>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingEmail( '<billing_cust_email>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingTel( '<billing_cust_tel>' );
$ccavenue->setBillingNotes( '<billing_cust_notes>' );

// copy all the billing details to chipping details
$ccavenue->billingSameAsShipping();

// get encrpyted data to be passed
$data = $ccavenue->getEncryptedData();

// merchant id to be passed along the param
$merchant = $ccavenue->getMerchantId();
```

```html
<!-- Request -->
<form method="post" name="redirect" action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp"> 
    <?php
        echo '<input type=hidden name=encRequest value="'.$data.'"">';
        echo '<input type=hidden name=Merchant_Id value="'.$merchant.'">';
    ?>
</form>

<script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
use Kishnio\CCAvenue\Payment as CCAvenueClient;

// Get Response
$response=$_POST["encResponse"];    

$ccavenue = new CCAvenueClient( '<merchant_id>', '<working_key>', '<redirect_url>' );

// Check if the transaction was successfull.
echo $ccavenue->response( $response );
```

or you can use this package also

https://github.com/softon/indipay